# vncserver auto start display for root

Tags: redhat, rhel5, vnc

In my rhel5 system there are cronjob scripts that are running as root which requires `export DISPLAY`.

I have added below lines in `/etc/sysconfig/vncservers` to start vncserver on certain displays  for users.

```
VNCSERVERS="3:root"
VNCSERVERARGS[3]="-geometry 800x600 -nolisten tcp -nohttpd -localhost"

VNCSERVERS="2:abc"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 800x600 -nolisten tcp -nohttpd -localhost"
```

but when I run `/etc/ini.d/vncserver start` it only starts dispaly 2 for user abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding VNCSERVERS variable. Doc in file says "*The VNCSERVERS variable is a list of display:user pairs.*".

You should use this form instead:

```
VNCSERVERS="2:abc 3:root"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 800x600 -nolisten tcp -nohttpd -localhost"
VNCSERVERARGS[3]="-geometry 800x600 -nolisten tcp -nohttpd -localhost"
```